# Pivot with 2 different types of columns

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
declare @tbl as table
(
    ItemId int,
    ProductDatasheetId int,
    ProductSpecName varchar(50),
    FiledType varchar(50),
    Value_Text varchar(50),
    Value_DateTime datetime,
    Value_Decimal decimal(18,3),
    ProdTestOpt varchar(50)
)

insert into @tbl
values (139, 1, 'Capacitor', 'Numeric', NULL, NULL, 11.000, NULL),
       (139, 1, 'Transistor', 'Numeric', NULL, NULL, 175.000, NULL),
       (139, 1, 'Insert Material', 'Option', NULL, NULL, 0.000, 'Brass'),
       (139, 1, 'Base Diameter', 'Numeric', NULL, NULL, 55.000, NULL),
       (139, 1, 'TestTube', 'Numeric', NULL, NULL, 130.000, NULL)

select 
    ItemId, [Capacitor], [Transistor], [Insert Material],
    [Base Diameter], [TestTube] 
from
    (select * 
     from @tbl 
     where FiledType ='Numeric') as t 
pivot
    (sum(Value_Decimal) 
        for ProductSpecName in ([Capacitor], [Transistor], [Insert Material], [Base Diameter], [TestTube])
    ) as pv

union

select 
    ItemId, [Capacitor], [Transistor], [Insert Material],
    [Base Diameter], [TestTube] 
from
    (select * 
     from @tbl 
     where FiledType = 'Option') as t 
pivot
    (MAX(ProdTestOpt) 
          for ProductSpecName in ([Capacitor], [Transistor], [Insert Material], [Base Diameter], [TestTube])
    ) as pv
```

I tried to pivot table with text and numeric value but pivot is not possible in single query.

I did them separately and when I try to union it throws an error.
is it possible to pivot by text and numeric value at the same time?

Expected output:

| ItemId | Capacitor | Transistor | Insert Material | Base Diameter | TestTube |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 139 | 11.000 | 175.000 | Brass | 55.000 | 130.000 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JOIN`, not `UNION`:

```
select
    i.ItemId,
    a.Capacitor,
    a.Transistor,
    b.[Insert Material],
    a.[Base Diameter],
    a.TestTube
from
(
    select distinct ItemId from #tbl
) i
left join
(
    select 
        ItemId, [Capacitor], [Transistor], [Base Diameter], [TestTube] 
    from
        (select * 
         from #tbl 
         where FiledType ='Numeric') as t 
    pivot
        (sum(Value_Decimal) 
            for ProductSpecName in ([Capacitor], [Transistor], [Insert Material], [Base Diameter], [TestTube])
        ) as pv
) a on i.ItemId = a.ItemId
left join 
(
    select 
        ItemId, [Insert Material]
    from
        (select * 
         from #tbl 
         where FiledType = 'Option') as t 
    pivot
        (MAX(ProdTestOpt) 
              for ProductSpecName in ([Capacitor], [Transistor], [Insert Material], [Base Diameter], [TestTube])
        ) as pv
) b on i.ItemId = b.ItemId
```

Gives correct result:

| ItemId | Capacitor | Transistor | Insert Material | Base Diameter | TestTube |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 139 | 11 | 175 | Brass | 55 | 130 |

There's probably a more elegant solution too, but this was the easiest thing that came to mind.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it is possible left query will not produce any result set and second query's result set will have data in that case even after join no result will produce

Comment: Can you give an example of this in your source data and the relevant expected outcome so I can adjust my answer accordingly? Are you talking about an ItemID which only has records with a `FiledType` of "Option"?

Comment: if you just update filter in the first query like this "where Field Type ='Numeric 123'" (update filter with this to presume that first query will not produced any data) and join with given below same query then result will not be produced that is why I did not use join

Comment: Ok, then you just need to start with the distinct list of `ItemID` values and join from that. I've updated my answer to do this.

Comment: yes that would do it , Thank you but as you said There's probably a more elegant solution too and I am not even close to it

Comment: Is there a reason you need a more elegant solution? If you have some performance issue with this solution, then you need to detail that in a question. As your question stands, this answer gives a valid solution IMO.

Comment: Thank you 30N1GM4 for your solution you think out the box and that's very impressive